# Why did English borrow verbs ending in -ish?

Tags: etymology, verbs, suffixes, loanwords, french

Why did English borrow verbs ending in *-ish*, but not in anything else, from French?
This seems quite obscure because it didn't import the verbs from the infinitive French forms, but through some sorts of obscure stems. I mean wouldn't it be more straightforward to use *finir* than *finish*?
As the etymology section of Wiktionary suggests, *-ish* comes from some sort of obscure French stem *-iss*. English borrowed *change* from Old French *changier*, why didn't it use the same deriving method with *-ish* verbs?
Dropping the *-r*, adding the *-en*, then dropping it again in Modern English. I'm not sure what that'd make an English verb from *finir* look like, but it seems like a more natural and straightforward route.

Comment: I would suggest that this is due to pronounciation and modifications that took place over time. Try imagining an English-native trying to pronounce *finir*.

Comment: I suspect we borrowed the present form, not the infinitive. So *finiss* and *poliss*. How and why did that get changed to *-ish*? I don't know.

Comment: Can you give more examples than 'finish'? Are you saying that English borrowed no other verbs from French than those ending in '-ish'?

Comment: The OED has _-ish_ _suffix_ "A suffix forming adjs., of Common Germanic origin; Gothic _-isks_, ON. _-iskr_, Old High German, Old Saxon, Old Frisian, Old English _-isc_, German, Dutch _-isch_: cognate with Greek -_ισκ-ος_ dim. suffix of ns., so I'm not entirely sure why you think this suffix is borrowed from French?  I'm sure there are others that do; _-esque_, for example.

Comment: I [advis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advise)ish that you re[consider](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consider)ish your claim about [import](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/import)ished French verbs.

Comment: Oh, I see.  "Finish" and a few other words (_e.g.,_ "burnish" and "diminish") **do** actually originate from French :)  I'not really sure to be honest, but it does seem to be a pronunciation thing that came about in ME.  There again, I don't really understand The Great Vowel Shift, either! ;)

Comment: @Mitch abolish, demolish, etc. pretty much the same formation.

Comment: @Anonymous I was talking about the verb ending, not the adjectival ending.

Comment: Vun-Hugh: many words ending in -ish in English come from the '-ir' verbs in French, like 'finir', which have a present participle '-iss-' used in some forms 'vous finissez' (but 'il finit'). Latin did not have '-iss-' in those cognate positions: 'finitis'; the addition of '-iss-' in later Romance is supposedly similar to English 'X-ize' suffix 'to make X', sterilize = to make sterile. As to your assumption that English didn't borrow any other verbs at all from French, that is entirely mistaken. Most verb borrowing into English from French are _not_ the '-ish' kind.

Comment: @Vun:  I realized!  Please see my second comment.  English, if you'll pardon the pun, is a language influenced from so many sources it is subject  to bizarre changes of spelling and pronunciation, which often makes etymology confusing or even impossible.

Comment: @Mitch "As to your assumption that English didn't borrow any other verbs at all from French" What are ya talkin about? When did I assume that?

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw You assumed it when you said "Why did English borrow verbs ending in -ish, but not in anything else, from French?". "Not anything else" means  that nothing else other than '-ish' verbs were borrowed from French; that, of verbs, English only borrowed those ending in '-ish'; that no verbs came to English from French except those ending in '-ish'. What do you think that first sentence was supposed to mean?

Answer (score 22):

There are a number of verbs ending *-ir* in modern French, where the corresponding English forms end with *-ish*. Some of them are *établir, finir, nourrir, polir, punir*. These are all conjugated the same way, so I'll just use *finir* as an example.

In modern French: *finir* is conjugated *je finis, tu finis, il finit, nous finissons, vous finissez, ils finissent*. So every form except 3rd person singular has an "s", and all these "s"s used to be pronounced. Borrowing the form *finis* rather than *finir* is quite understandable, since it probably occurs just as often in ordinary conversation. And having /s/ turn to /sh/ is a very common sound change in many languages.

What I don't know is whether the change from /s/ to /sh/ happened in Middle English or in Anglo-Norman French. (It didn't happen in the French currently spoken in Paris.) Maybe a linguist could tell us.

Comment: The _-ss-_ in the French conjugation derives ultimately from the Latin inchoative suffix _-sc-_; i.e., Fr. _finir_ < Lat. _fīnīre_, but Fr. _finiss-_ < Lat. _fīnisc-_ (with _fīniscō_ being the inchoative of _fīniō_ in Latin). Since Latin ⟨sc⟩ (= /sk/) became [stʃ] and then [ʃ] before front vowels already in Proto-Romance and then later on [sː] and eventually [s] in French, I would think it more likely that the stem actually ended in [iʃ] when English started borrowing the French verbs. French then lost [ʃ] later on (and then regained it when /tʃ/ > [ʃ]), but English did not.

Comment: [s] > [ʃ] is common enough in quite a lot of languages—but not in Romance- or English-speaking areas. Modern German does it in certain positions before consonants, but that’s about the only place in Germanic languages that change happens regularly. [ʃ] > [s], on the other hand, is known to have happened in most of the Romance-speaking area (except Italian and Romanian).

Comment: We see the [s] > [ʃ] change also in "leash."

Comment: @suməlic Or the other way around there as well: it’s ultimately from _laxus_ (I’m guessing probably with metathesis of /ks/ to /sk/), and in Italian we have _lasciare_ with [ʃ].

Comment: I think the change here was vocalization of /k/ to /j/, yielding /js/ (like how /kt/ became /jt/), rather than metathesis. But I'm not sure. French has a different reflex of /sk/ in "fraîche." I don't think French had [ʃ] > [s] historically; my impression was that fronting of the reflex of vulgar Latin palatalized /c/ occured while it was still an affricate, so [tʃ] > [ts].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: oops, I forgot to ping you with my last comment. Actually, I don't even know if there is any evidence for a [tʃ] stage in the history of French, or if people just postulate it on theoretical grounds.

Comment: @suməlic You may be right; I'd have to look more into it. That would leave the /sh/ of the English _-ish_ verbs unexplained, though. It's rather too much of a coincidence for my taste that they happen to coincide with cases that all derive from combinations of /k/ and /s/ in Latin/Proto-Romance (and have /ʃ/ in Italian), never simple /ss/. It's only a guess, but it wouldn't be so uncommon for /tʃ/ and /ʃtʃ/ to have differing reflexes (viz., /ts > s/ and /ʃ > s/ respectively).

Comment: Another thing to remember is that Anglo-Norman French wasn't exactly the same language as the one that evolved into Parisian French. I think @Janus has made a pretty good case that these verbs were pronounced /ʃ/ (in at least some conjugations) in Anglo-Norman French.

Comment: Perhaps this sound change is related to what we see with nouns that end in *tion* in English, pronounced with the SH sound (forgive me for not using the fancy symbols), corresponding to the French cobnates that end in *tion*, with a non-SH sound.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could it be because of the original Latin spelling *sc*? *Sc* represented /ʃ/ in Old English.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw I don't think so—it wasn't spelt that way in Old French, as far as I know, and the link to the Latin inchoatives was probably fairly opaque to speakers by then.